# symfony2 : apply different template with special parameter?

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

How can I apply different template (view) when I type **?t=1** in the url ?

Examples :

```
mysite.com -> opens home with default template, let's say home.twig
mysite.com/?t=1 -> opens home with another template : home1.twig (or 1/home.twig)
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just read parameter in controller and render template: `'home'.$t.'.html.twig'`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can define different routes for this, but second url should look like "mysite.com/1":

```
route_1:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Index:home }

route_2:
    pattern: /{t}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Index:custom }
    requirements:
        t: '[0-9]+'
```

A second approach is to load different views based by existence of "t" parameter:

```
public function homeAction(Request $request)
{
    $view = $request->query->has('t') && $request->query->get('t') == 1 ? 'home1.twig.html' : 'home.twig.html';
    return $this->render($view, $params);
}
```

Comment: I have to clear cache after this update (_app/console cache:clear_) ? (the server is in production mode with no debug)